# Save each username and password into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text file with the following

> username,password
>
> admin,admin123

and would like each username and password to be saved into the same array so that it looks like this

> [0] = > username
>
> [1] = > password
>
> [2] = > admin
>
> [3] = > admin123

This is my code currently:

```
 $accounts = file("password.txt");

 foreach($accounts as $account) {
      $user = preg_split("/,/", $account ) ; 
 } 

 print_r( array_values( $user ));
```

It seems to only save each line into the array and then overwrites it with the next username and password.

**Clarification:** This is for a beginner PHP course, not for an actual site. I know passwords are never supposed to be stored in plaintext...

Comment: I hope your users know you are storing their passwords in plaintext. You probably could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php that won't give you what you asked for but should be useful.

Comment: Why would you possibly want an array like that, its useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `$user` an array and append values to it using `[]` notation.

```
$accounts = file("password.txt");
$user = array();
foreach($accounts as $account) {
    list($name, $pass) = preg_split("/,/", $account ); 
    $user[] = $name;
    $user[] = $pass;
    // Or use array_push($user, preg_split("/,/", $account ));
}
print_r( array_values( $user ));
```

Clarification: To set a specific key in an array the syntax is `$var["key"]`, by omitting the key argument PHP treats `$var[]` as an append/push and appends the value to the end of the array `$var`.

Comment: But won't this make it `array(0=>array(username,password), 1=>array(admin,admin123))` instead of `array(0=>username,1=>password,2=>admin,3=>admin123)`?

Comment: @Andrew You're absolutely right, my bad. Updated the code example, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @PedroLobito Not really, he posted it first, he only changed it because it wasn't creating the same structure that the OP wanted. FYI I think your answer is still better.

Comment: check the edit...1m after I posted mine he edited his answer.

Comment: @PedroLobito I think that was in response to the comment I raised above, which was also 1 minute after you posted.

Comment: It really doesn't matter to me but it's not polite. GL @andrew.

Comment: @PedroLobito I can assure I didn't copy you. For what it's worth I didn't know that [] works inside list(). My first edit did not change the code at all, only added the clarification paragraph below to explain what I did in the code.

Comment: Wait - you're getting all BH over a copy of an answer @PedroLobito? Didn't we just have a similar conversation?

Comment: @JayBlanchard , yes we did, but as far as I remember you have posted a comment, right?

Comment: Ah, that's right. Gotta know where to draw the line @PedroLobito ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

There no need for a `preg_split` or `array_values`, `explode` and `list` will do the job, i.e.:

```
$accounts = file("password.txt");
 foreach($accounts as $account) {
      list($user[], $user[]) =  explode(",", $account) ;
 }
 print_r($user);
```

Comment: I think this answer is better because of the use of `list` and `explode`. Regular expression is overkill for this sort of thing. Another option instead of `explode` is [`str_getcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is overwriting user variable. declare a user array like the below code.

```
$accounts = file("password.txt");

foreach($accounts as $account) { 
    $user[] = preg_split("/,/", $account ) ; 
}

print_r( array_values( $user ));
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use the code below"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.